# Revision id display resembles vote display

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

The sight of revision ids startled me, as my intuition falsely led me to believe my recent edit had two downvotes. Comparison of the two:

[image: Comparison of displays]

This is no biggie of course, but perhaps it would be a good idea to change the style of the revision ids so they are less similar to the vote display, for the sake of angsty newcomers?

Comment: The down arrow is a dropdown indicator, which can be clicked to expand and view the revision details.

Comment: I disagree. It looks nowhere like the vote indicator: there's only one arrow, it's beside the number rather than below, there's no minus sign beside the number and it's not even placed on the same page or in the same situation.

Comment: Kudos for coming to Meta and asking. At 5 rep, you have recently earned the privilege to participate in Meta, and used it well. You question is clear and well written, so +1 for that. And as a feature request, I agree that the revision arrow could use a different look and feel.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak  I don't think you can agree or disagree.  If we have ONE user who thinks like that, there are probably others.  I agree to someone who knows a bit more about SO, it's obvious they are not the same (the absence of a "-" in front of the 2 is obvious there are no downvotes, in any case).  But if one person finds they are similar you can be sure more people think it